# Oracle PL/SQL: How can i assign &value to local variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can I assign `&a` to local variable in Oracle PL/SQL?

I wrote this code:

```
declare
  temp1 number;
 begin
  temp1:=&a;
  dbms_output.put_line('The value of temp1 is' || temp1);
end;
```

but I got this error: "**Encountered the symbol "&" when expecting one of the following:**"

[image: Error]
What is the problem in this simple code?

Comment: Your tool simply don't support `&variables`. Try it out in `SQL*Plus`. [Oracle Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch5.htm#i1211130)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your query in Oracle  sql developer (11g) ... It's working fine... Output is also coming fine

Comment: you can see screenShot here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5dnfQ6gMrLuUTVDQ1pldWRHVTQ/view
@user2798256

Comment: i just test this code in "test window"(test script), @user2798256 where you test this code?

Comment: you try this query in some different tool ... eg: toad,sql developer

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL tool does not appear to support substitution variables.

You could try a bind variable instead:

```
declare
    temp1 number;
begin
    temp1:=:a;
    dbms_output.put_line('The value of temp1 is ' || temp1);
end;
```

You might be better switching to another tool, such as SQL Developer.

Comment: but when i integrates substitution variables within a query , this work fine in my SQL tool...

Comment: Do you mean they work ok in a SQL query, just not in a PL/SQL block? What tool are you using?

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, but I had a look on their website - there appears to be a way of turning substitution variables on or off. See about halfway down this page: http://www.allroundautomations.com/bodyplsqldev100.html

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

I ran this code in "sql window", instead of "testing window", and now everything works well!

Thank you all!